# Pandas - get row and column name for each element during applymap

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare one list of strings for similarity and get the results in a pandas dataframe for inspection; so I use one list as index and the other as column list. I then want to compute the "Levenshtein similarity" on them (a function that compares the similarity between two words).

I am trying to do that using `applymap` on every cell, and compare the cell index to the cell column. How could I do that? Or simpler alternatives?

```
things = ['car', 'bike', 'sidewalk', 'eatery']
action = ['walking', 'caring', 'biking', 'eating']
matrix = pd.DataFrame(index = things, columns = action)

def lev(x):
    x = Levenshtein.distance(x.index, x.column)  
matrix.applymap(lev)
```

so far I resorted to use the following (below) but I find it clumsy and slow

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame(data = [action for i in things], index = things, columns = action)
for i, values in matrix.iterrows():
    for j, value in enumerate(values):
        matrix.ix[i,j] = Levenshtein.distance(i, value)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on the dataframe, and to access columns' values use `.name`:

```
def lev(x):
    #replace your function
    return x.index + x.name
a = matrix.apply(lev)
print (a)
                  walking          caring          biking          eating
car            carwalking       carcaring       carbiking       careating
bike          bikewalking      bikecaring      bikebiking      bikeeating
sidewalk  sidewalkwalking  sidewalkcaring  sidewalkbiking  sidewalkeating
eatery      eaterywalking    eaterycaring    eaterybiking    eateryeating
```

EDIT:

If need some arithemtic operation use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
a = pd.DataFrame(matrix.index.values + matrix.columns.values[:,None], 
                 index=matrix.index, 
                 columns=matrix.columns)
print (a)
             walking       caring           biking         eating
car       carwalking  bikewalking  sidewalkwalking  eaterywalking
bike       carcaring   bikecaring   sidewalkcaring   eaterycaring
sidewalk   carbiking   bikebiking   sidewalkbiking   eaterybiking
eatery     careating   bikeeating   sidewalkeating   eateryeating
```

Or:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(matrix.index.values + matrix.columns.values[:, np.newaxis], 
                 index=matrix.index, 
                 columns=matrix.columns)
print (a)
             walking       caring           biking         eating
car       carwalking  bikewalking  sidewalkwalking  eaterywalking
bike       carcaring   bikecaring   sidewalkcaring   eaterycaring
sidewalk   carbiking   bikebiking   sidewalkbiking   eaterybiking
eatery     careating   bikeeating   sidewalkeating   eateryeating
```

Comment: brilliant - thank you. but would there be no way to achieve that has a vectorized/elementwise operation?  What you do is essentially what i ve been doing with iterrows

Comment: It depends what you need. If need some arthemtic operation only, use numpy.

Comment: I see thank, but i am not after arithmetic operation, rather into applying a simple function to each cell like in the question. I thought applymap, being an elementwise method would do.

Comment: Yes, but ther is no connection with index and column values in `applymap` - check it by `a.applymap(lambda x: print (x))`

Comment: OK so i understand I would have to iterate with apply  / iterrows anyway. A bit disappointing, but thx

Comment: Not sure, but if check [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316) apply can be faster. But if apply in each loop some function, maybe it is same pefrform.

Comment: I'm confused, I get AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name' and AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index' when I  try `return x.index + x.name`. My dataframe  is made of integers.

Comment: @rkian: you have a separate issue, please post a separae question, cite this question and answer in a link, and we'll gladly look at it. Most likely, if you get *"object has no attribute 'name'"*, then you accessed a single cell, not a series, so probaly you tried to `.apply()` on a single series, not a dataframe.

Answer (score 9):

You can do that by "nested `apply`" as follows:

```
things = ['car', 'bike', 'sidewalk', 'eatery']
action = ['walking', 'caring', 'biking', 'eating']
matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=things, columns=action)
matrix.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x).apply(lambda y: LD(x.name, y.name), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
          walking  caring  biking  eating
car             6       3       6       5
bike            6       5       3       5
sidewalk        7       8       7       8
eatery          6       5       6       3
```

The call `pd.DataFrame(x)` here is because `x` is a `Series` object and the `Series.apply` is similar to `applymap`, which does not carry `index` or `columns` information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a combination of apply and comprehension:

```
def mapping_function(value, index, column_name):
    # this is called for each cell
    mapping_result = column_name + '|' + str(index) + '|' + str(value)
    return mapping_result


def _column_mapping_function(column_series):
    column_name = column_series.name
    new_series_data = [mapping_function(value, index, column_name) for index, value in column_series.items()]
    new_series = pd.Series(data=new_series_data, index=column_series.index)
    return new_series
    
result = indexed_data_frame.apply(_column_mapping_function)
```